# How to check if a PostgreSQL table is temporary?

Tags: postgresql, system-tables, temporary-tables, catalogs

How can I write a query to check if a PostgreSQL (10.x) table is a temporary table?

I looked at the `pg_class` system table, but couldn't find any column about whether the relation is temporary.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE False;
 relname | relnamespace | reltype | reloftype | relowner | relam | relfilenode | reltablespace | relpages | reltuples | relallvisible | reltoastrelid | relhasindex | relisshared | relpersistence | relkind | relnatts | relchecks | relhasoids | relhaspkey | relhasrules | relhastriggers | relhassubclass | relrowsecurity | relforcerowsecurity | relispopulated | relreplident | relispartition | relfrozenxid | relminmxid | relacl | reloptions | relpartbound 
---------+--------------+---------+-----------+----------+-------+-------------+---------------+----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+------------+--------+------------+--------------
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html#id-1.10.4.13.4)

> relpersistence:  p = permanent table, u = unlogged table, t = temporary table